# Apple and Google play integration with backend

Tags: applepay, google-pay

We currently have a .NET Core 2 backend. We have features exclusive to paying members only. We are currently using Authorize.net for payments and subscriptions.

Does apple / google pay return something that we can send to our backend as proof a payment has been made so that we could generate account information?

EDIT:

I found this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/businesschat/supporting_apple_pay/processing_payment_requests

Would I have to implement this on my backend and the mobile client posts to it?

EDIT2:

So I did more reading and it seems like apple/google pay is only used to collection payment data. Then we have to send that to a payment processor like stripe or braintree to make the actual payment? Am I going on the right track?

Edit:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6

I found this and it looks like I can give apple a url to post to with information about the subscription. This is exactly what I need. Howeverm it looks like google only has some kind of pub/sub thing?
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications

There's no restful way to do it?

Comment: You're confusing in-app docs with on the web. Both Google and Apple have native payment APIs on their respective platforms (Android and iOS). If you are building a website, you cannot use those. They both now offer web-based payments, but those are achieved via the Payment Request API as detailed in my answer. Long and short, there is no direct payment processing through Google or Apple Pay on the web. You need your own processor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. On the web, Apple and Google Pay both utilize the Payment Request API in HTML5. This particular API only returns the payment information, not a payment token. You are responsible for turning it into a payment token through your payment processor of choice.

I'm unsure of the capabilities of Authorize.net, but both Stripe and Braintree have Apple/Google Pay integration that takes care of this for you. You use their API instead of the Payment Request API directly, and under the hood their code uses the Payment Request API to get the user's payment information, sends it to their servers to get tokenized, and returns you the token. As a result, using Stripe or Braintree is more seemless, but ultimately any payment processor will do.

Comment: Authorize.net provides us a payment form we can host in an iframe. It collects payment data and does the processing for us. It then posts back to our server with the information which we then use to make an account according to what service was selected. If we wanted to do subscriptions through apple and google pay, would that be apis that the app store or play store would provide?

Comment: I think you may have confused these payment services with in-app billing that both Google and Apple provide. It's a separate product and has its own API (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview). Google Pay, as you correctly asserted, only collects the payment information and you still need to use a payment processor. The purpose of that API is for non-digital goods, so in-app billing is probably the correct course for you.

Comment: It's worth noting that Google Pay does not solely operate through Payment Request API. It's also possible to add support for Google Pay online using the client libraries for the Web and Android.

Comment: The web client library uses the Payment Request API.